# CLI : Is There A Script To Skew Image With A Curve

Tags: image, skew

Looking for a script that will skew an image for me through the command line.

The skew needs be a curve; stead the angle skews offered by [imagemagick](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/skew/index.php) or lunapic.

I want it to look like it is placed up in a celestial sphere.
Basically able to fit inside of [these boxes](http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-fr...-image11717706).

Alsor, can CSS do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it using a program called POVRay and a little bit of script hacking... if interested, check it out the full explanation at linuxquestions.org: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4764944